# Prevent .AppleDouble folders on NFS shares

Tags: macos, sharing, nfs

I've got at home:

- a Debian server running multiple services, including NFS shares;
- one Mac that I use most of the time
- several Android devices
- a Windows client

All happily access the files on the server, as read/write.

Now for some reason my Mac thinks it's smarter than every one else and puts all of his turds in every folder. I understand there's a value added when doing this on local HFS shares (or on the server's HFS TimeMachine partition). However when dealing in public (I mean on a server shared with foreign OSes), I think it should behave and keep it to the minimum.

The Mac is a laptop, but it is most of the time sitting on a desk with external keyboard/screen/mouse, which means it keeps the NFS shares mounted most of the time. Which is nice. Which means it keeps watching everything and puts his .AppleDouble turds everywhere as soon as they are deleted.

```
$ find . -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
$ find . -type d -name .AppleDouble|wc
      0       0       0
...
$ find . -type d -name .AppleDouble|wc
   1251    3109   38017
...
$ find . -type d -name .AppleDouble|wc
   2810    9992  113386
```

This happened in less than one minute. So server side hacks such as read only or remove .AppleDouble with a cron script are just no go.

Is it possible to just tell the Mac to keep it shut when using shared spaces?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/306108/disable-creation-of-appledouble-files-on-mac-os-x Personally, I've always used BlueHarvest to keep network disks clean. [BTW, Windows does the same thing, even on native NTFS disks, but the meta remains hidden even with OS/hidden files etc showing.]

Comment: I've read this question and its answers, BlueHarvest feels like a hack to me. I don't want to delete the folders, I want OSX to behave.

Comment: OSX **is** behaving ;) It's doing what it needs to do to not lose associated information when writing to drives that don't support the resource fork. You could argue that it ought to do it the way Windows does, for compatibility & to remain hidden… but people have been arguing that for years, without getting anywhere.

Comment: When you're visiting a relative that requires that you remove your shoes, you won't keep them just because you're used to keeping them at home. That applies to computers, when using a shared space you follow the common rules. **I don't want any OS to put any OS-specific files on these NFS shares**. I don't want any Thumbs.db or desktop.ini either, but that's another topic.

Comment: Then join the queue & shout at Apple.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for a solution... I'll join the queue until then.